# Question about the equivalence between the categories of affine group schemes and Hopf algebras over $k$.

Tags: algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras

There is a proof given [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~sawant/SS2016/AG.pdf) (Theorem 1.3.4) of the equivalence between the categories $\mathbf{AffGrpSch}/k$ and $\mathbf{HopfAlg}^{opp}_k$.

The author writes in the line before the theorem that there is a canonical functor $\mathbf{AffGrpSch}/k \to \mathrm{Fun}(k-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Set})$. Is this a mistake? Because in the diagram in the statement of the theorem the functor is $\mathbf{AffGrpSch}/k \to \mathrm{Fun}(k-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Grp})$.

How is the functor $\mathrm{Fun}($k$-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Set}) \to \mathrm{Fun}($k$-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Grp})$ defined in the diagram? Specifically, what does 'induced by the forgetful functor' mean in the right side of the diagram?

Another question, on page 9 would it not make sense to write $\mathbf{HopfAlg} \to \mathrm{Fun}($k$-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Grp})$ after the author writes that we write $h^A$ for the functor $k-\mathbf{Alg} \to \mathbf{Grp}$?

Comment: This looks like an error. The forgetful functor gives a functor in the opposite direction (by composing with it). I don't think there is any (non-trivial) functor going in the other direction.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you please help me with how to go about fixing the error? What changes would need to be made in the statement to fix the error?

Comment: After looking at it for a while, I think it is simply a matter of reversing that particular arrow.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. Before the statement of Theorem 1.3.4., it is written that "there is a canonical functor $\mathbf{AffGrpSch}/k \to \mathrm{Fun}(k-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Set})$". Here $\mathbf{Set}$ would also need to be changed to $\mathbf{Grp}$, yes?

Comment: No, that part is correct (note that it explicitly mentions that this is induced by the forgetful functor).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft And is the same thing also correctly written on page 9?  I'm referring to the part where it is written that "The above discussion shows that the canonical functor...". Sorry for bothering you with too many questions. I just need to make sure if the proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is also correct there.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft One last question, there are two other instance besides the diagram (one before the statement of the theorem and one in the middle of the proof) where it is written that $\mathbf{HopfAlg}^{opp}_k \to \mathrm{Fun}(k-\mathbf{Alg}, \mathbf{Set})$. In these places too $\mathbf{Set}$ would need to be changed to $\mathbf{Grp}$, yes?

Comment: I don't actually think there is anywhere where that needs to be changed. The only thing that seems to be wrong is the direction of the arrow in the diagram.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I understand now. Is my assumption correct that the "$=$" in the diagram means this is an equivalence?

Comment: Yes, the equality sign in the diagram indicates that we identify those categories (in fact, they are the same by definition).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: By the way, I recommend taking a look in Jantzen's book to see all of this in a mixture of more and less detail (most of the proofs are less detailed, but it contains a lot more information about everything).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I will do that. Thank you.